# sendbird createMyGroupChannelListQuery return empty when recall

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vuejs2, sendbird

I'm using SendBird Javascript SDK `createMyGroupChannelListQuery()` and the instance's `next()` method to retrieve the list of group channels. However, it will return the list only one time after initialized the instance, the next time it gets called, it result is always an empty array. Since I need to fetch the channels multiple times I need to have the full list of channels always. Please let me know if you have experienced this.

```
// Retrieve a list of channels
var listQuery = sb.GroupChannel.createMyGroupChannelListQuery();
listQuery.includeEmpty = true;
listQuery.order = 'latest_last_message'; 
listQuery.limit = 100;   // The value of pagination limit could be set up to 100.

if (listQuery.hasNext) {
    listQuery.next(function(groupChannels, error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error.
        }

        // A list of group channels is successfully retrieved.
        groupChannels.forEach(channel => {
            ...
        });

        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To call it again and get the result, just call:

```
listQuery.hasNext = true;
```

Comment: I tried to take out `listQuery.hasNext` condition still it returns empty array. I need to create a new query but re-call everything again doesn't work `createMyGroupChannelListQuery()` doesn't give me a new query. It will only work if I refresh the page, this function is called in Vue app and it gives empty array every time the component state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sandbox for you to try:

https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-has-next-problem-fducb?file=/src/index.js

Change `APP_ID` and `USER_ID`

Check the console, it should appear "**First time**" and the list of channels and then "**Second time**" and again the list of channels.